# when returning a view from Child Ajax Form it redirects to child forms url instead of refreshing the child ajax form only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

Child ajax form redirects to the URL http://www.AppName/Email/Email/AttachmentList instead of refreshing the AttachmentList view only.

Here is the child form (View Name: Attachment List)

```
        @foreach (var attachment in Model.Attachments)
        {
            <li>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RemoveAttachment", "Email", new { area = "Email" }, new FSIAjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "uploadedFilesSection" }, new { @id = "fromEditRole" + attachment.IdString }))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => attachment.IdString)
                    <span><a `enter code here`href="@Url.Content("~/File/GetFile")?folder=EmailAttachments&file=@(attachment.AttachName)" target="_blank">@attachment.OriginalName</a></span>      
                  <button type="submit" class="imageButton removeButton" title="Remove"></button>
                }
            </li>
        }
```

Here is the Controller Action

```
    [Authorize]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult RemoveAttachment(FormCollection fm)
            {
                EmailViewModel model = SessionData.GetCurrentObject<EmailViewModel>();

                if ((fm.AllKeys.Contains("attachment.IdString")) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["attachment.IdString"]))
                {
                    var attachment = model.Attachments.Where(x => x.IdString == fm["attachment.IdString"]).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (attachment != null)
                    {
                        FileHelper.RemoveFile("EmailAttachments","",attachment.AttachName);
                        Directory.Delete(WebConfig.SharedFileContainer + @"\EmailAttachments\" + attachment.IdString, true);
                        model.Attachments.Remove(attachment);
                    }

                    SessionData.SaveCurrentObject<EmailViewModel>(model);
                }

                return View("AttachmentList", "Email", new { area = "Email" });

            }

public ActionResult AttachmentList()
            {
                EmailViewModel email = SessionData.GetCurrentObject<EmailViewModel>();

                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return PartialView(email);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("AttachmentList", "~/Views/Shared/Wrapper.cshtml", email);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the ajax js file referenced.